# Subplot several scatter histograms

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, scatter-plot, scatter

Can someone share an example to create 4 scatter hist plots as a subplot?
To clarify. I am planning to create a pdf of plots. Each page will have 4 subplots. Each subplot being the scatter histogram.

The example of creating scatter histogram seems to be [this](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/axes_grid1/scatter_hist_locatable_axes.html)

Would there be any alternate functions to do this in fewer lines than using this scatter plot example and sub-plotting each of them ?

Comment: What exact problem do you face? Are you able to create 4 subplots? (`fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,2)`) Then use the example for each of the four axes in `axs`?

Comment: Apologies for lack of clarity. i was wondering if there would be a shorter way than wrapping up the example into function and creating subplots from them. If there was already a subplot_hist function in some library or  in matplotlib as one exists in matlab.

Comment: Seaborn has a [`jointplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html) function, but that explicitely does not allow to be used in subplots. But I don't see the problem of placing a `def function` in front of the code from the example.

Comment: You can also look at [these alternatives](https://764-100939689-gh.circle-artifacts.com/0/home/circleci/project/doc/build/html/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_hist.html) coming from a not yet published documentation update of mine. They simplify creating a single such scatter histogram; but are not well suited to create subplots.That is to say, you already found the best option in the docs using the `axes_grid1` approach.

Answer (score 3):

Using the linked example, all you need to do is increase the number of [subplots](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html).

Then for each subplot, you go through the example code to make each one a scatter histogram.

I've pasted a toy example below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10),nrows=2, ncols=2)
print(axes)
colors = ['r','b','g','m']

for row in axes:
    for axScatter in row:
        print()
        x = np.random.randn(1000)
        y = np.random.randn(1000)
        # the scatter plot:
        # gets color from the end ('m' will be first)
        color = colors.pop()
        axScatter.scatter(x, y,color = color)
        axScatter.set_aspect(1.)

        # create new axes on the right and on the top of the current axes
        # The first argument of the new_vertical(new_horizontal) method is
        # the height (width) of the axes to be created in inches.
        divider = make_axes_locatable(axScatter)
        axHistx = divider.append_axes("top", 1.2, pad=0.1, sharex=axScatter)
        axHisty = divider.append_axes("right", 1.2, pad=0.1, sharey=axScatter)

        # make some labels invisible
        axHistx.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelbottom=False)
        axHisty.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelleft=False)

        # now determine nice limits by hand:
        binwidth = 0.25
        xymax = max(np.max(np.abs(x)), np.max(np.abs(y)))
        lim = (int(xymax/binwidth) + 1)*binwidth

        bins = np.arange(-lim, lim + binwidth, binwidth)
        axHistx.hist(x, bins=bins,color=color)
        axHisty.hist(y, bins=bins, orientation='horizontal',color=color)

        # the xaxis of axHistx and yaxis of axHisty are shared with axScatter,
        # thus there is no need to manually adjust the xlim and ylim of these
        # axis.

        axHistx.set_yticks([0, 50, 100])

        axHisty.set_xticks([0, 50, 100])

plt.show()
```